# How to attach MacOSX Shark to a process as soon as it starts?

Tags: macos, shark

Is there a way to tell Shark to attach to a process (by name) immediately as it sees it running ?

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be a very useful feature, since you can't predict how much time would pass between the program starting and Shark being able to attach to it. Why don't you have Shark launch the program instead?